# Visual Studio throws SEHException when debugging IOT Core on fresh installation

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

I have created a nearly blank Windows IOT Core background task and if I include a method that use the "double" data type it will throw an SEHException if I step-over it after hitting a breakpoint.  I have seen these weird things before when the versions of IOT Core installed on the PC vs. Raspberry PI don't match, but as far as I can tell I have things matching.  Any ideas?

I have tried:

- Changing the target min/max version in the VS Project.
- Updated to the latest Universal Windows nuget packages
- Ensured that the OS version on the PI (10.0.17763.107) matches the UAP version show in visual studio (though is says 10.0.17763.0), I can't find any way to change that
- Even downloaded newest version of VS 2019, same thing

Simple code (do not step-into the method, if you do that it works):

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        double x = DoNothing();
        Debug.WriteLine(x);
    }

    public double DoNothing()
    {
        return 300.7D;
    }
}
```

Exception I get when step-over:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBSb3.jpg

Comment: Hi Joshua Mason, please add try-catch to see if it can catch this except and show ExternalException.ErrorCode value when it occurs.

Comment: Try..Catch block doesn't really do anything because it seems like the exception is actually coming from Visual Studio itself.  

Here are the odd behaviors:

- If I just run the code it works fine
- It only happens if I am debugging and step-over the method call
- If I actually step-into the method it works!!!

Here is another image: https://imgur.com/ZBkHjBt

Comment: I can reproduce this issue when set mini target version to 17763 and contact the related engineer for this issue. A workaround is set mini target to 15063 (I tested and it worked).

Comment: Ok, glad to know this is reproducible by someone else.  Only problem is that if I set the min. target back that far my source code no longer works as it has dependencies on framework/features that are only available in newer versions (such as HttpListener).  My code also relies a lot on floating point data types (float, double, decimal, etc.) so I basically can't develop because I can't debug.  Hopefully there will be a fix or the company I am working for is going to have some huge issues...

Comment: 16299 support HttpListener but unfortunately it also can reproduce this issue. Currently the workaround is adding some logs to monitor your program instead of using debugger.

Comment: When will this be resolved?  Not being able to the debugger sucks and is massively slowing down my development time and the taking away the reason why I purchased Visual Studio....

Comment: Hi Joshua Mason, the issue seems related to VS debugger you can report a problem follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).